# TV Digital com Stickers

Tags: lua

Não sei se posso postar isso aqui. Mas acho que sim. O que esta acontecendo é o seguinte eu tenho que fazer meu artigo, e meu orientador me deu o tema Desenvolvimento de Aplicativos para TV digital utilizando stickers. Pesquisei sobre stickers mas não tem muito matérial na internet, na verdade não tem quase nada, a minha impressão foi que criaram a plataforma e abandonaram. Disponibilizaram uma apostila bem mal feita e pronto. Gostaria de saber se alguem já mecheu, se tem alguns apps que podem me passar, apostila, algo que eu possa estudar para fazer meu artigo.
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Infelizmente esta pergunta especificamente é off-topic. Mas se você tiver alguma dúvida mais específica, sobre como fazer alguma coisa ou por que algo não está funcionando como deveria, poderemos ajudar.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o chat, e trocar uma ideia com o pessoal